# Identifying active network interface

Tags: c#, .net, networking

In a .NET application, how can I identify which network interface is used to communicate to a given IP address?

I am running on workstations with multiple network interfaces, IPv4 and v6, and I need to get the address of the "correct" interface used for traffic to my given database server.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The simplest way would be:

```
UdpClient u = new UdpClient(remoteAddress, 1);
IPAddress localAddr = ((IPEndPoint)u.Client.LocalEndPoint).Address;
```

Now, if you want the NetworkInterface object you do something like:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
   IPInterfaceProperties ipProps = nic.GetIPProperties();
   // check if localAddr is in ipProps.UnicastAddresses
}
```

Another option is to use P/Invoke and call [GetBestInterface()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365920(vs.85).aspx) to get the interface index, then again loop over all the network interfaces. As before, you'll have to dig through `GetIPProperties()` to get to the `IPv4InterfaceProperties.Index` property).

Comment: after some research I'm finding that the "best" answer means:
1. The first IP of the adapter with the matching route/default gateway combo with the lowest metric.
2. In case of a metric tie, the adapter with the lowest binding order wins.

Answer (score 6):

Neither of these will actually give the OP the info he's looking for -- he wants to know which interface will be used to reach a given destination.  One way of doing what you want would be to shell out to the **route** command using System.Diagnostics.Process class, then screen-scrape the output.  `route PRINT (destination IP)` will get you something useable.  That's probably not the *best* solution, but it's the only one I can give you right now.

Answer (score 3):

The info you are after will be in WMI.

This example using WMI may get you most of the way:

```
using System.Management;
string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration";
ManagementObjectSearcher moSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection moCollection = moSearch.Get();// Every record in this collection is a network interface
foreach (ManagementObject mo in moCollection)
{    
    // Do what you need to here....
}
```

The [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217.aspx) class will give you info about the configuration of your adapters e.g. ip addresses etc.

You can also query the [Win32_NetworkAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(VS.85).aspx) class to find out 'static'about each adapter (max speed, manufacturer etc)

Answer (score 2):

At least you can start with that, giving you all addresses from dns for the local machine.

```
IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName);

foreach (System.Net.IPAddress address in hostEntry.AddressList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(address);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to give a complete picture: another approach would be to use `Socket.IOControl(                        SIO_ROUTING_INTERFACE_QUERY, ... )`

ConferenceXP includes rather comprehensive function wrapping this, works with IPv4/6 and multicast addresses: https://github.com/conferencexp/conferencexp/blob/master/MSR.LST.Net.Rtp/NetworkingBasics/utility.cs#L84

Comment: full code example for querying the routing table by `Socket.IOControl` can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26611456/684096)

Answer (score 0):

this a old thread but today I'm looking for this, but find a better answer, I think.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get ifIndex of ip (ip address to connect)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ip">IP Address that want to connect</param>
/// <param name="description">Lan card description</param>
/// <param name="ifIndex">interface index</param>
/// <param name="ifAddress">IP Address of Lan Interface</param>
private static void CheckInterface(string ip, out string description, out int ifIndex, out IPAddress ifAddress)
{
    description = "";
    ifIndex = -1;
    ifAddress = IPAddress.Any;
    var myIp = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()) return;
    foreach (var adapter in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if (!adapter.SupportsMulticast) continue;
        if (adapter.OperationalStatus != OperationalStatus.Up) continue;
        var properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
        if (!properties.MulticastAddresses.Any()) continue;
        var p = properties.GetIPv4Properties();
        if (p == null) continue;
        foreach (var ipInfo in properties.UnicastAddresses)
        {
            if (ipInfo.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Address:{0} == {1}", ipInfo.Address, myIp);
                var adpIp = ipInfo.Address.GetAddressBytes();
                var cmpIp = myIp.GetAddressBytes();
                if ((adpIp[0] == cmpIp[0]) && (adpIp[1] == cmpIp[1]) && (adpIp[2] == cmpIp[2]))
                {
                    description = adapter.Description;
                    ifIndex = p.Index;
                    ifAddress = ipInfo.Address;
                    return;
                    //Console.WriteLine("Name {0} ifIndex {1}", adapter.Description, p.Index);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Today, works for me! (when ifIndex is -1, not found an interface)