# Programmatically add rules to "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security snap-in"?

Tags: c#, windows-7, firewall

Is there any library in .NET that would allow me to manipulate the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security in Windows 7?

The reason I ask this is because, I want to be able to add program/port exceptions programmatically.

For example, I want to add program.exe to the Inbound Rules section and for this program, I want to allow TCP port 5660 and UDP port 5660. All other ports should be blocked for this program alone;

I reasoned that this could be comfortably set in the Inbound Rules Section in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security; I hope this is the best way of doing it?

However, how would I accomplish that programmatically?

I have already seen an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113755/programmatically-add-an-application-to-windows-firewall), but I think this one talks about "Allow a program through Windows Firewall snap-in", which does not have the port information.

Answer (score 9):

Greg's answer in this question helped me.

[Any way to turn the "internet off" in windows using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242566/any-way-to-turn-the-internet-off-in-windows-using-c)

Comment: Indeed, that answer is totally covering this question. Would that qualify this post as duplicate?