# hnetcfg.dll throws BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, windows-firewall, badimageformatexception, windows-firewall-api

Executing code that references `c:\windows\system32\hnetcfg.dll` to manage the Windows Firewall from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242566/any-way-to-turn-the-internet-off-in-windows-using-c), causes a `BadImageFormatException` as soon as the DLL is loaded.

Opening the 414KB DLL file in *NUnit* for inspection throws the same exception.

I am running Windows 7. Any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

### Solved:

...by setting target platform to x86.

Answer (score 4):

Is it a 64-bit application trying to reference a 32-bit dll? If so, either get the 64-bit version of the dll or force the application to run in 32-bit using

```
corflags /32bit+ myApp.exe
```

Or as you say, just build in 32-bit (x86)

Comment: The service using the DLL is now targeted for x86. How can I make sure it will run on 32-bit and 64-bit machines? Do I need two different versions of my application, or can I just target x86? I am running 64-bit Windows and it seems to be working, but I'll need to test it properly.

Comment: If (at least) one of your dependencies is 32 bit, then you'll need to force the application (service) to run in 32-bit mode. Targetting for x86 will mean it'll run in 32-bit mode on both x86 and x64 which may be all you need. If you'd like it to run 64-bit on x64, then you'll need to source a 64-bit version of the dll and essentially have two separate executables - one for x86 (build against x86 dll) and one for x64 (build against x64 dll).