# NetworkInterfaceType is always NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10789898) to see which Network card my program uses. When I look at the properties of the returned [NetworkInterface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface(v=vs.110).aspx) object, the `NetworkInterfaceType` enum is always `NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet`, but in the enum I can see also a definition for GigabitEthernet.

```
public enum NetworkInterfaceType
{
    Unknown = 1,
    Ethernet = 6,
    Ethernet3Megabit = 26,
    FastEthernetT = 62,
    FastEthernetFx = 69,
    GigabitEthernet = 117,
}
```

And all Netword cards that are used are all Gigabit Ethernet cards (Realtek PCIe Gigabit, Realtek USB 3.0 Gigabit network, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Adapter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation of the [NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype(v=vs.110).aspx) Microsoft wrote that they only return some of the possible values:

> This property only returns a subset of the possible values defined in
>   the NetworkInterfaceType enumeration. The possible values include the
>   following:
>
> - Ethernet
> - Fddi
> - Loopback
> - Ppp
> - Slip
> - TokenRing
> - Unknown

To see if you use 1000Base or 100Base, you have to look at the [NetworkInterface.Speed Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.speed(v=vs.110).aspx). This includes the speed as a long value in bit. So Gigabit shows speed of `1000000000` and use this value to difference between them.

This confused me a bit until I found the hint in the documentation. Maybe it helps others, too that run into the "issue".

Comment: This documentation from Microsoft is still on their website in the exactly same wording as cited by you, but it's obviously wrong, because on my laptop I also get the values `Wireless80211` and `Tunnel`.

Comment: Well, they're writing 'The possible values include the following:', so in my understanding that value collection is not self-contained. However, it's at least confusing, or simply wrong.

Comment: Got the same value than @TobiasKnauss on my computer with PCIe wireless card. Funny contradiction: "only returns a subset" clearly excludes other values, while on NetworkInterfaceType page, in remarks, we have "This enumeration defines the values returned by the NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType property.", which means it can indeed return any values from NetworkInterfaceType.