# What is the network that my pc is connected?

Tags: vb.net

I want to know which Network interface my computer is connected. Because I want to get the correct Subnet Mask and IPv4 address.

Example: My computer is connected to "Home" network, and I know that is wireless, but imagine I connect to the same network by cable, How can I identify which network interface is.

How can I do that?

Comment: @AlexB. it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Wrong link. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359596/identifying-active-network-interface).

Comment: @AlexB. is something like that thanks