# How can I identify the network adapter (or interface) name used for a successful ping in a window bat or powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, networking

Is there a  way to identify the network adapter (or interface) name used for a successful ping

eg I have the following adapters:
[image: Network Adapters]

I perform the command

ping google.com

which is successful,  I would like to know that the adapter used is either "Wi-Fi"  Sunrise_5GHz_387918

There is a similar question for c#
[Identifying active network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359596/identifying-active-network-interface)

But I am looking for a windows batch file way (possibly powershell).

Comment: One possibility is to use WMIC, if it is installed on your computer: `%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe /NameSpace:\\root\StandardCimv2 path MSFT_NetAdapter where "InterfaceOperationalStatus='1' and Virtual='FALSE'" get name`

Comment: Just be aware, there can be more than one connected network device at any one time. This means that it is possible that you may incorrectly identify the wrong one, because the above comment code, and all of those in the accepted answer can each output multiple results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in PS using:

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter | select netconnectionid, name, InterfaceIndex, netconnectionstatus
```

OR,
You can use `netsh`

```
netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces
```

In the newer version of PS like in windows 8, you can even directly use:

```
Get-NetAdapter | SELECT name, status, speed, fullduplex | where status -eq 'up'
```

Note by that the *netconnectionstatus* value indicates the connection status. *2* indicates `connected`

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell, you can determine which network adapter was used for pinging a particular address with the `Test-NetConnection` cmdlet. The returned object will have several properties that identify the adapter that was used, including:

- `InterfaceAlias`: The name of the adapter
- `InterfaceIndex`: The index of the adapter
- `NetAdapter`: An object representing the network adapter, similar to `Get-NetAdapter`

To get the adapter that successfully pinged Google, you could use the following:

```
$NetAdapter = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 8.8.8.8
$NetAdapter.InterfaceAlias  # Returns (e.g.) 'Ethernet 2'
$NetAdapter.InterfaceIndex  # Returns (e.g.) 15
```